# Error "The item "obj\Debug\abcd.Global.resources" specified more than once in "Resources" .Duplicate items not supported by "Resources" parameter

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services

I am working on old .net application where there multiple files and folders under the project name. There is a folder WebServices which has its own SLN file, `global.asax` files.

When I exclude this project the build is successful. But as I add include this folder, there is a build error of `Duplicate items not allowed in references parameter`.

I cannot remove any of global files from references. Please suggest some solution as I have to make some code changes in `track.asmx` file in webservices folder and build without errors.

Comment: Did you try to delete the obj and bin folders? They will be restored when building. If may have been under the source control, that you are working under, is holding a filelock on files that should be replaced in the build process. Always do a "Clean Build" when your issues are in the obj and bin folders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried the above solution but still getting tha same error. "/ / " specified more than once in Resources... Actually there are 2 references of global file. One is from webservices folder and other present under project abcd solution.